# MySQL / PHP Joining tables without always having common column

Tags: mysql, join

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all the answers for my original question.
I now have another problem related to these queries though. After I join the tables I would want to search for NULL results, following my example below I would like to search for surname=NULL/surname='', but it returns an empty result, even though there are 2 non-linked ones.

Example Query:

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE table2.surname=NULL
```

This returns 0.

Any ideas? I can understand the logic behind why it would return 0, but there must be a way to get this to work (?)

**Original Question:**
I can't find any answers on my question and probably it's because I don't know what I should be looking for.

The problem I have is that I want to join 2 tables **with** a common indicator but include records where the common indicator also doesnt exist..

Maybe I'm making no sense, but I'll try to explain in code below

Table1

```
id | name
1 | John
2 | Michael
3 | Anna
4 | Sue
```

Table2

```
id | surname
1 | Doe
2 | Anderson
```

So I would like a query that outputs/binds the tables like so:

```
table1.id | table1.name | table2.id | table2.surname
1 | John | 1 | Doe
2 | Michael | 2 | Anderson
3 | Anna | NULL | NULL
4 | Sue | NULL | NULL
```

So, merge where there is data, and dont merge where this is no data (or add NULL value).
The table2 will always have less data than table1, so table1 could be used as a bone.
vlookup does this perfectly in Excel, returns N/A where the value is not found
I know how to achieve this with PHP but I'm trying to speed up my code, when working with records well above the 50k I don't want to single query every row for another table column.

I've tried the WHERE table1.id=table2.id, but it only joins them if table2.id exists, I've also tried the JOIN ON function, but it does the same.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

See [this excellent Jeff Atwood's post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Figured it out while writing the question, then tested it :) Superb though, and yes that of course works :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN ON table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```

Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

LOL.
Sometimes I find that if I write my question in a way that someone else will be able to help me, I kind of figure it out....
I had been looking for the solution for this for over 4 hours, but while writing it I started to think about what my early day courses says about LEFT/RIGHT join...

Well... sorry if I took up anyone's time :)

The correct query if anyone else would be wondering is:

```
SELECT table1.*,table2.* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
```