# MySQL Join tables without having common column at all, just by order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the same problem described in this other question:

[MySQL / PHP Joining tables without always having common column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471641/mysql-php-joining-tables-without-always-having-common-column)

But my tables don't have ane field in common, and i only want to join them "the first one with the firs one", "the second one with the second one" and so on.

Example:

### Table_1

- john
- mary
- charles

### Table_2

- smith
- goodman
- bush

### TableResult

- john | smith
- mary | goodman
- charles | bush

Tables should allways have the same ammount of items, but if not, the unexisting items could be filled with null, as "henrry | null".

Perhaps it could be done adding first a field to number each row, or something so, but performance is critical here.

Comment: Don't try this. Within minutes of actually executing the SQL, DBAs from all over the planet will converge on your location with all manner of instruments of torture.

Comment: How do you know what the physical order of the records will be?

Comment: the order on table_1 and table_2 doesn't matter (in fatc they will be select results made on random list of names).

Comment: Are you trying to use a database to 'randomly' generate first name / last name combinations?

Comment: Yes, i have a big list of names and surnames from different locations with weight values indicating how common the name is in each moment, so i need to use a database. The question now is, should i make the mix in database or in code once selected the Table_A and Table_B items...? :/

Comment: When you create the tables, why didn't you create them with an auto-incrementing primary key?  That would make this much easier.

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a good idea, and can never be guaranteed consistent results, but you can get the row number of each table and use that as your joining field.

Try somemthing like this:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM (SELECT Field1, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
      FROM Table1
         JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r) t1
 JOIN (SELECT Field2, @curRow2 := @curRow2 + 1 AS row_number
      FROM Table2
         JOIN    (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r) t2 on t1.row_number = t2.row_number
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/218c5/4).

This will only work if both tables have the same number of rows.  If not, you'll be missing data...

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, sgeddes, this is a working solution ;)  The question now is, should i use it or is it too bad for performance and is better to bring data from the two tables and make the mix on code? Aren't this variables @curRow too time consuming?

Answer (score 0):

If you want performance just use integer primary keys but you do need keys. You CAN NOT AND SHOULD NOT do it the way you described. :)

Comment: perhaps i shouldn't :D  But i think this could be done at least numbering the results on Table_A and Table_B some way, and then Join on this fields. Do you mean that will be better for performance send two queries to the database and make the mix on code? (this will be a web site with many users)

Comment: Well if to be honest i would store first name and surname in same table.  on otherhand if the id fields are set as primary keys then mysql qill be able to use indexing and if you use LEFT JOIN to join the tables in a single sql statement then i cant see how this could impact your performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Given that your requirements are specifically to achieve random results, I think you can make use of a `cross join`.

The following [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23c00/8/0) captures my effort to demonstrate this.

--

Otherwise, if your data is truly constant (in which case, why are you using a database?) then it could produce consistent results - but you could just as easily define keys and be done with it. If not, consider what happens with your expectation that "the unexisting [sic] items could be filled with null" when you grow the database:

### Before

**Table 1**

```
foo
bar
```

**Table 2**

```
qux
```

**Result**

```
foo qux
bar null
```

### After

**Table 1**

```
foo
bar
baz
```

**Table 2**

```
qux
quxx
```

**Result**

```
foo qux
bar quxx
baz null
```

You can't add `baz quxx` to the database.

Comment: This is a tool to get 10 random items from a table with names to make Table_a, and 10 random items from a table with surnames to make table_b, to mix then this tables record by record to have 10 random composition of "name surname" unexisting people. :)

Comment: How do you plan to make it random? Otherwise, you're just trying to get the Cartesian product. Use a cross join. See [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23c00/8/0) as an example of how you can read random combinations.

Comment: I solve my random with the following, with Number being a field to weight the chance for a name or surname to be used:    SELECT Name FROM Table_A WHERE SOME_CONDITIONS ORDER BY (RAND() * Number)  LIMIT 10;

Comment: How would that not just apply the weight to all the rows? I don't quite get it. I think cross join + random order makes the most sense for your purpose, as my example shows.

Comment: Well, it seems to work right, but i can't ensure becouse is an idea from other source... This could be a better alternative, perhaps...     SELECT Name, (RAND()/Number)AS Pond  FROM Table_A WHERE SOME_CONDITIONS ORDER BY  Pond  LIMIT 10;

Comment: Your solution seems to have good performance, but the problem is that the name and surname can't be repeated (no "John Doe" and "John Smith" allowed in the final result.